# How to send and receive cookies by react js to a SAP server?

Tags: reactjs, postman, setcookie, http-proxy-middleware

Let me try to explain a bit my current situation:

I have to consume an api rest from SAP which I need to get a token and a X-CSRF-Token, both work well, I got them and the session cookies from SAP, until this point everything is ok. To consume the api rest I have to send by headers this both tokens and the session cookies.

The problem is that the browser blocks the cookies because they don't accomplish with some criteria like:

- This set cookie was blocked because it has the secure attribute but was not received over a secure connection
- This set cookie was blocked because its domain attribute was invalid with regards

At the beginning I could not connect with SAP cause CORS policy of Same Origin, I already solved it with http-proxy-middleware, I do the calls by axios (I have activated withCredentials: true to let it know that I need the cookies) . But now the problem looks like it is still for cookies because the result that I receive after call the api is 403 Forbidden.

I already made the test by postman and everything worked well, I could get the tokens a cookies and consume the service from SAP, the problem is by the client-side (browser).

Additionally, I don't have access to backend to configue cors and cookies, so a solution by backend-side is not what I am looking for. Moreover to build a proxy-server by node.js is my last option, before that, I want to know if I can control this situation only by the client, I'm using react JS for this.

This is part of my code conditioned:

**Proxy**

```
const { createProxyMiddleware } = require('http-proxy-middleware');

module.exports = function(app) {
    app.use("/oauth2/token",
        createProxyMiddleware( {
            target: "https://sapConnectionOauth.com",
            changeOrigin: true,
            secure:true,
            cookieDomainRewrite: {
                "*": "sapConnectionOauth.com"
            }
        })
    );
    app.use("/http/serviceIWannaUse",
        createProxyMiddleware( {
            target: "https://sapConnection.com",
            changeOrigin: true,
            secure:true,
            cookieDomainRewrite: {
                "*": "sapConnection.com" 
            }
        })
    );
};
```

**Service I want to use**

```
export const serviceIWannaUse = async (token, xcsrf) => {
    console.log('entra a serviceIWannaUse')

    let config= {
        url:
            "/http/serviceIWannaUse",
        method: "POST",
        withCredentials: true,
        headers: {
            Accept: "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "X-CSRF-Token": xcsrf,
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
    };
    return await axios(config)
};
```

**This is an Image of example how setCookies appear in the browser (It is not mine)**

[image]

Also I have been modifying the google flags for cookies and it has not worked. The link is only: chrome://flags/

If someone can help me with this I'll be really thankful.